# Should i call $destroy on scope after test finished?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

In my test i create Angular controllers with a hand made `$scope`:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('ContentController', {$scope: $scope});
  });
});
```

Is it necessary to call `$scope.$destroy()` after every test run?

```
afterEach(function() {
  $scope.$destroy();
});
```

Comment: I have never done, tests are short lived anyways. Unless you have some event handlers on $destroy event that you want to check.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary, only semantics.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$destroy

Comment: I use it for controllers, it doesnt mention tests.